# Generate random colours that contrast nicely with white text

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I have a random colour generator that works as expected, however I am wanting to use white text on top of whatever colour I generate and of course, this is no good when the colour generated is light as the contrast makes the text unreadable.

```
const generateColour = () => '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6);
```

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any way in which my current code can be altered to mean that I only receive colours dark enough to be of a accessible contrast ratio?

Comment: Tried selecting colors, putting them to `array`. And randomizing this? 

Comment: use HSL and a constant S and L ranges, H can be anything

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html

Answer (score 0):

Use HSL, either directly in CSS or convert to RGB. Select S & L fixed ranges so colors won't be too light.

```js
let count = 10;
while(count--) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="color-chip" style="background-color:hsl(${Math.random()*360|0}deg,${Math.random()*30|0+60}%,${Math.random()*35|0+20}%)">TEXT</div>`);
}
```

```css
.color-chip{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  height:30px;
  width:50px;
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HSL colours so you can control the hue, saturation and luminance independently.

- **Hue**: assign a random value 0-255.
- **Saturation**: assign a random value 0%-100%, or if that looks too grey you could adjust the range from 50%-100% or use a fixed value.
- **Luminance**: assign a random value 0%-50% (to avoid the lighter shades), or if the results look too dark then try a fixed value around 40% or 50%.

```js
let s = '<p>variable saturation 0%-100% and variable luminance 0%-50%, dark results</p><div>'
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  const hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) // integers 0-255
  const sat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) // integers 0-100
  const lum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51)  // integers 0-50
  s += `<span style="background: hsl(${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%)">${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%</span>`
}
s += '</div><hr><p>variable saturation 0%-100% and fixed luminance 40%, lighter results</p><div>'
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  const hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) // integers 0-255
  const sat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) // integers 0-100
  const lum = 40
  s += `<span style="background: hsl(${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%)">${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%</span>`
}
s += '</div><hr><p>variable saturation 50%-100% and fixed luminance 40%, less grey</p><div>'
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  const hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) // integers 0-255
  const sat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51) + 50 // integers 50-100
  const lum = 40
  s += `<span style="background: hsl(${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%)">${hue}, ${sat}%, ${lum}%</span>`
}
s += '</div>'
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', s)
```

```css
div {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

span {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

hr {
  border-top: #bbb;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

It will be easier to spot the differences if, after running this snippet, you use the **full page** link to see all the results on one page.